# What is the best practise in choosing a table's primary key

Tags: android, sqlite, realm

I used to create a column called 'id' which is auto incremented in any table I create. While in some cases I found that this column is useless while another column like 'citizen_ssn' is a better candidate to be the primary key.

So, what is the best practice in choosing the table's primary key ?
Should I use what will fit the need or create the auto-incremented column or another opinion ?

Comment: In my opinion this depends on how you want to control de duplicate citizen if you want to controle it by code It's better auto-increamented in the other hand If you prefer that DataBase controle it you should use PK in citizen_ssn

Comment: It is recommended that you use a dedicated column for the ID where the value will remain constant. If `citizen_ssn` is user supplied or could otherwise change, it's not a good idea to use it as primary key.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In `Realm` there is no real reason to have an *auto-increment* primary key. (although if your server returns primary key info, then it's useful to know that you're referring to the same object).

In SQLite (or any relational database) the reason you *need* them is that that is the only way you can link two objects together (through JOINs) - for example, a many-many relationship is done with a Join Table that contains the primary key of both linked tables as a foreign key.

In Realm, you can link objects together as a field like `private OtherObject otherObject;`, and many relation as `private RealmList<OtherObject> otherObjects`. So you don't need primary key to create relationship.

What you might need them for in Realm is if you want to use `insertOrUpdate()` method to update an existing object in Realm by its primary key, overwriting it with an unmanaged object. You can also edit objects by calling the managed object's setters, so this is not entirely necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Any attribute which is unique and not null can be used as a primary key. Generally `id` is used as a primary key by many developers. But there's no such rule except mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

What is a Primary Key?

Apart from Auto-Incrementing it, a primary key is used to Identify a row. As every row is unique, so is the Primary key. Two or more rows with a column number `n` can have the same value, let's say "Australia" but the column with Primary Key constraint will have the unique value.

So, it's not important to use the `id` column as a primary key.

One can use `phoneNumber` as a PK too. 
Depends on the usage.

I hope I've made myself clear.